# What does it mean when my jtextfield has "<dynamic>" written instead of the text I imported from a file?

Tags: java, swing, dynamic, jtextfield, windowbuilder

I imported a `String` `ArrayList` from a file and I tried to write the first string (position 0) of the array in a `JTextField`. The word is not on the text field, instead of it, I have the word `<dynamic>` written there.

[image]

Here's the code:

```
txtTEST = new JTextField();
String title =gl.getGL().getBooks().get(0).getTitle();
System.out.println(title);
txtTESTE.setText(title);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

< dynamic > means that this text field has not a static string (e.g "Hello world"). Window builder will show it, when the value of the field is a variable.

```
gl.getGL().getBooks().get(0).getTitle();
```

This is a variable, hence the window builder will show **< dynamic >**.

As far as i remember though (i have not used windowbuiler for almost a year), if you give a `final` variable to the field, window builder will be a able to spot it and show the correct value. Something like

```
private static final String HELLO_WORLD = "Hello world!";
...
textField.setText(HELLO_WORLD);
```